# Ruby: Escaping special characters in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

I am trying to write a method that is the same as `mysqli_real_escape_string` in PHP. It takes a string and escapes any 'dangerous' characters. I have looked for a method that will do this for me but I cannot find one. So I am trying to write one on my own.

This is what I have so far (I tested the pattern at [Rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/) and it worked):

```
# Finds the following characters and escapes them by preceding them with a backslash. Characters: ' " . * / \ -
def escape_characters_in_string(string)
  pattern = %r{ (\'|\"|\.|\*|\/|\-|\\) }
  string.gsub(pattern, '\\\0') # <-- Trying to take the currently found match and add a \ before it I have no idea how to do that).
end
```

And I am using `start_string` as the string I want to change, and `correct_string` as what I want `start_string` to turn into:

```
start_string = %("My" 'name' *is* -john- .doe. /ok?/ C:\\Drive)
correct_string = %(\"My\" \'name\' \*is\* \-john\- \.doe\. \/ok?\/ C:\\\\Drive)
```

Can somebody try and help me determine why I am not getting my desired output (`correct_string`) or tell me where I can find a method that does this, or even better tell me both? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you put `start_string` into `escape_characters_in_string` and you don't get what you're expecting? What is that incorrect output? You've given us what you expect to see, now tell use what you actually see...

Comment: When I `puts` the results of `escape_characters_in_string(start_string)`, nothing changes; it prints out the contents of the `start_string`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your pattern isn't defined correctly in your example. This is as close as I can get to your desired output.

Output

```
"\\\"My\\\" \\'name\\' \\*is\\* \\-john\\- \\.doe\\. \\/ok?\\/ C:\\\\Drive"
```

It's going to take some tweaking on your part to get it 100% but at least you can see your pattern in action now.

```
  def self.escape_characters_in_string(string)
    pattern = /(\'|\"|\.|\*|\/|\-|\\)/
    string.gsub(pattern){|match|"\\"  + match} # <-- Trying to take the currently found match and add a \ before it I have no idea how to do that).
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

I have changed above function like this:

```
  def self.escape_characters_in_string(string)
    pattern = /(\'|\"|\.|\*|\/|\-|\\|\)|\$|\+|\(|\^|\?|\!|\~|\`)/
    string.gsub(pattern){|match|"\\"  + match}
  end
```

This is working great for regex

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
print %("'*-.).gsub(/["'*.-]/){ |s| '\\' + s }
\"\'\*\-\.
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ActiveRecord sanitization methods: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-sanitize_sql_array

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at escape_string / quote method in Mysql class [here](http://tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/)