# The quick way to escape characters in Ruby for ERB

Tags: ruby, escaping, erb

I'm using ERB and trying to include a number of strings. I ran into a problem when the strings start containing questionable characters like `"` or `\`.

I looked at this SO's post:
[Ruby: Escaping special characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140582/ruby-escaping-special-characters-in-a-string)

Which could solve my problem, but I have about more than a dozen variables to be templated, and calling that method to each of the variable seems a bit of a tedious job. So, before I go ahead and start calling `escape` all over, I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Why are these characters questionable? Are you escaping for JavaScript, HTML, or something else?

Comment: what's an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have templated JSON files and I need to insert string values in there. As soon as strings contain the quotation marks `"`, it terminates the string, and JSON becomes invalid. So I need to prepend them with the backslash character. It's not just quotation marks, EOL characters also causes problems. So I need to escape the strings. Since I have more than a dozen of them, I would need to call `escape` so many times. It's fine, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

%q seems to handle [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/) pretty well:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :089 > %q{ ' " \ \\ \/ \b \f \n \r \t \u ^F}
# => " ' \" \\ \\ \\/ \\b \\f \\n \\r \\t \\u \u0006"
```