# Ruby escaping a set of special characters in a string

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have a set of special characters for Elasticsearch that I need to escape with Ruby.

They are: `+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`

How can I get any string to escape any of these characters?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140582/ruby-escaping-special-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 4):

The problem as it is stated has no solution, because “escaping two subsequent characters” makes no sense. What result do you expect to receive “escaping”, say, `&&`?

I believe, you want to escape all single characters, so that `&&` becomes `\&\&` and `||` — `\|\|`. That is easy.

```
to_escape = %w_+ - = & | > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /_ # C"mon, SO parser
re = Regexp.union(to_escape)
print 'str (f) | a || b'.gsub(re) { |m| "\\#{m}" }
#⇒ str \(f\) \| a \|\| b
```

Another possibility would be to use [`Regexp#escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape), but it will escape more, than you probably need (e. g. spaces.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on @mudasobwa's answer, using the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that uses a hash for replacements:

```
escapees = %w$ + - = & | > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / $
  #=> ["+", "-", "=", "&", "|", ">", "<", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}",
  #    "[", "]", "^", "\"", "~", "*", "?", ":", " /"] 
h = escapees.each_with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = "\\#{c}" }
  #=> {"+"=>"\\+", "-"=>"\\-",..., " /"=>"\\ /"} 
h.default_proc = ->(h,k) { k }
```

If the hash `h` does not have a key `k`, [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) causes the `h[k]` to to return `k`.

```
s = 'str (f) | a || b'
ss = s.gsub(/./,h)
  #=> "str \\(f\\) \\| a \\|\\| b" 
puts ss
  #=> str \(f\) \| a \|\| b
```