# Execute a shell script in Ruby passing HTML/PHP code as an argument

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, sh

I've got a **HTML/PHP** code that I pass through a Ruby function. I want it to render a minified PHP rather than just as is. I recon that the shell command `php -w` would be perfect to do so.

```
module Haml
  module Filters
    module PHP
      include Base
      ##
      # @param text, string (Haml/PHP code)
      #
      def render(text)

         `php -w <<< "<?php #{text} ?>"`

      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above code breaks because the HTML/PHP string `text` contains special characters. What is best way of escaping them?

---

After posting this question and thanks to comments I did more trial and error.

I established it is caused by only four special characters: `" \ $ (backtick)` (double quote, backward slash, dollar sign, backtick)

I created a [simple solution that works (below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59670461/6260775).

Comment: Not entirely clear if this resolves your issue, since you haven't provided a [mcve]... (Can you provide an example of "PHP and HTML code and all sorts of special characters", so anyone reading this question can have some confidence that a proposed solution actually works?), but perhaps [`Shellwords.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) will suffice?

Comment: It is difficult to give an example... I run the code on large number of files and kinda not sure what breaks it really... just got to the point that I think it only breaks on escaped double quotes in php code. My Ruby (homebrew) doesn't seem to have shellscape module

Comment: You may find it convenient to use single quotes when appropriate. The rule for single-quoted strings is that each pair of backslashes is treated as one backslash and a single backslash not followed by a backslash is treated as a single backslash unless it is followed by a single quote, in which case the pair are treated as an escaped quote.

Comment: [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) has forms that permit you perform the three substitutions you mention with a single `gsub`. Let `str = 'a\b"c$e'`. One is to use a block: `str.gsub(/[\\"\$]/) { |s| case s; when "\\" then "\\\\\\"; when '"' then "\\\""; else "\\$"; end } #=> "a\\\\\\b\\\"c\\$e"`. Another is to employ a hash: `h = { '\\'=>'\\\\\\', '"'=>'\\"', "$"=>'\\$' } #=> {"\\"=>"\\\\\\", "\""=>"\\\"", "$"=>"\\$"}`, then `str.gsub(/[\\"\$]/, h) #=> "a\\\\\\b\\\"c\\$e"`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland updated my question, moved to a new solution; escaping from an escaping that is escaped can be pain... If I have a chance to test it I'll improve my solution

Comment: Lastly, you don't need the word 'EDIT'. Just edit as though you are writing an article, provided you don't change the question.

Answer (score 2):

Passing content in on the command line is not just risky, but the wrong way to do it in the first place. Use tools like [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) to do it by *streaming it in directly* which avoids the need for escaping altogether.

Feed the input to the STDIN filehandle of your `php -w` process:

```
output = ''

Open3.popen2('php', '-w') do |stdin, stdout, wait_thr|
  stdin.write("<?php #{text} ?>")
  stdin.close
  output << stdout.read
end
```

Comment: Similar advice applies to using backticks or `Kernel#system`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this answer:  [Ruby: Escaping special characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140582/ruby-escaping-special-characters-in-a-string)

it sounds like that after you've read your file in, you need to strip out the characters.

```
file = File.open("users.txt")
file_data = file.read
clean_data = file_data.gsub(/\\/, '')
```

Then print your data to the shell command (You may to do some more escaping)

Comment: Yes, saw that answer, doesn't work in with php and shell... but I think I've picked-up the trace of solution, just need to escape few characters really: \, ", $

Comment: @Matt If you're writing shell commands you **must** use `shellescape`. Don't just half-ass it with this minimal substitution.

Comment: Just realising this... :-)

Comment: @MaciekRek can you mark this answer as correct if it works with `shellescape`

Answer (score 0):

The below substitution chain seems to work, but as some people pointed out a possible better solution would be using **shellescape**.

```
# a breakdown of escaped characters

text.gsub("\\", "\\\\\\")  #   \ backslash (the escape character) 
text.gsub("\"", "\\\"")    #   " double quotation mark
text.gsub("$", "\\$")      #   $ dollar sign
text.gsub("`", "\\\\`")    #   ` backtick
```

Amended code

```
module Haml
  module Filters
    module PHP
      include Base
      def render(text)

         text=text.gsub("\\", "\\\\\\").gsub("\"", "\\\"").gsub("$", "\\$").gsub("`", "\\\\`")

         `php -w <<< "<?php #{text} ?>"`

      end
    end
  end
end
```